# Connstring value was encrypted

Tags: encryption, web-config

I have a web.config file. We recently change the database that we are using.
The connection string value was encrypted. See below.

```
  <appSettings>
     <add key="CommandTimeOut" value="31" />
     <add key="ApplicationName" value="Arch" />
     <add key="EnableDatabaseAuditing" value="False" />
     <add key="LastTransactionIDParameterName" value="LastTransactionID" />
     <add key="CurrentDateTimeDB" value="ArchRefDataDB" />
     <add key="connString" value="AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAKGHR.........."
```

I have tried to encrypt the new database and I have the encrypted value and replace the connstring value.
Unfortunately, I'm encountering error.

Here is the error when I tried to access the site... Error Id :421a46fd-2690-4480-a6cb-0794f07f95e3 
Error Type: five - ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing 
Error Message :An unhandled exception has occurred.

Error InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The web server has been unable to contact the Federation Server. at System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.WSPersistentState.GetPersistentInfo(TrustedRealm& trustedRealm, String& fsAccountName) at System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.WebSsoAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateWithWSFederationPassive() at System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.WebSsoAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object o, EventArgs args) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Accenture.Web.Security.Adfs2008ModuleInitiate.InvokeOnEnter(Object source, EventArgs e) at Accenture.Web.Security.IdentityIntegrationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Please advise.

Comment: It looks like it's Base64 encoded, not really encrypted.

Comment: Hi Shark, what to do you mean by Base64 encoded? I'm new on this programming world. And how can I generate this Base64 using the new database?

Comment: [Link 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), 
[Link 2](https://www.base64decode.org/)

Comment: I think the value comes from using DataProtectionConfigurationProvider encryption.

Comment: Hope someone can help me work on this. Thank you.